# AutoCompleteExtender works good but not in the place it should be

Tags: asp.net, css, ajax, positioning, autocompleteextender

I've followed the standard example of in 
http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/autocomplete/autocomplete.aspx which demonstrates using AutoCompleteExtender. Everything works fine but the auto-complete appears with about 20 pixel distance below the bottom of its target control. I mean they are not glued to each other as they should be. I've not changed anything and also I've not applied any special styling using CSS or anything else. why this ugly distance is formed while the control is rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the padding issue of the CSS of the extender, which by not defining any CSS associated to it, by default, it supposes a padding of 2px.